# Not able to trigger any event after dialog is closed in Android

Tags: android, dialog

I have an activity called ConvertActivity that has a button, which calls SetPrecisionActivity dialog.  After the dialog is displayed and the user presses the close button, the onResume() or onRestart() of ConvertActivity is not been called.  I need to do some processing after returning to the ConvertActivity.

ConvertActivity.java

```
public class ConvertActivity extends Activity {
private int callingActivity;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.convert_layout);

 } 

public void onClick(View view) {
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.setprecision:
    // show the precision screen
    SetPrecisionActivity.app_launched(this);
    break;
}
  }
}
```

the convert layout

```
  <TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="*"  
android:stretchColumns="*"
android:padding="15dp"
android:background="#ffffff">
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_span="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/setprecision"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/setprecision"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="@string/csetprecisionh" />
</TableRow>
```

the setprecisionActivity.java (which will be shown as a dialog box)

```
  public class SetPrecisionActivity {
  private static Spinner spinnerp;

  public static void app_launched(Activity mContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("helloapp", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    showPrecisionDialog(mContext, editor);
    editor.commit();
}   

public static void showPrecisionDialog(final Activity mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle("Set precision ");

   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) mContext.findViewById(R.id.popupprecision);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.setprecision_layout, viewGroup);

   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
   close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.setContentView(layout);        
    dialog.show();        
}
 }
```

Comment: Your `SetPrecisionActivity` class is just a helper, not an Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ConvertActivity is not paused or destroyed when you open another Activity, it just 'sits' there. Look at the startActivityForResult method and wait for the Result, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result) for example.

Comment: I agree that the ConvertActivity just sits there, but I would have thought that it would be paused or something while the dialog is active and when we close the dialog, it should have resumed or restarted something..

Comment: One might think. It definitely isn't destroyed, might be paused but you aren't guaranteed. Have a closer look at the Activity lifecycle docs. Anyway, the usual way when you want to wait for another Activity to finish, then do something is the way I described above.

Comment: True, I have changed my code as you have mentioned to get the necessary results and it worked.. thanks a lot.

Comment: This solution will only work if you re-implement the dialog as an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger an event when a dialog is clossed you need an "on dismiss" listener.
It's already answered here: [Can you fire an event when Android Dialog is dismissed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203720/can-you-fire-an-event-when-android-dialog-is-dismissed)