# How to handle AlertDialog close event?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

Is there a callback when an AlertDialog is closed using the touch outside event? I have this enabled "setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)". I want to set a visibility of a specific view once the AlertDialog is closed using the touch outside event. Any ideas?﻿

I am using the AlertDialog.Builder() inside a Fragment if that helps.

Comment: Here is an answer for similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786285/12285529

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an [OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) seems most appropriate, but it requires a relatively high API level, so you might need to stick with an [OnCancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the AlertDialog documentation. That was really a quick one.

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder.setOnDismissListener() is API level 17, but Dialog.setOnDismissListener() is API level 1 and has the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

I post Kotlin version because i was looking for it today and i had hard time

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())

builder.setTitle("title")
builder.setMessage("message")

builder.setOnCancelListener {  func->Log.i("meh","meh") }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are within custom dialog class, and wish to catch 'clicked outside dialog' event - override cancel(). If you wish to catch any'dialog closed' event - override dismiss().
I recommend inserting logic BEFORE super.dismiss(). Kotlin example:

```
override fun dismiss() {
    Utils.hideKeyboard(mContext, window)
    super.dismiss()
}
```