# Set time between alert dialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am showing an alert when a user exits a certain area:

```
   /*Function to show alert when Geofence breached*/
   private void showAlert() {
       final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Geofence Breached");
        builder.setMessage("User has breached the Geofence Boundary!");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.show();
    }
```

And I am calling it like so:

```
 if( distance[0] > mCircle.getRadius()  ){                      
     showAlert();
```

}

Is there any way to set it that an alert only goes off every 2 minutes as the location is getting checked all the time then the notification keeps appearing. I have read about, Timers, Timertasks and alarmManagers but I dont think it will work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to cancel the dialog after 3 mins from the time it opened ?

Comment: @RajeshCP No I seen a solution to that, my user may click OK and at the moment it displays another alert instantly, I want to set it that an alert can only be shown every 2 minutes if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a member variable in your Activity/Service to record the time when the dialog was last shown:

```
long timeDialogShown = 0;
```

When checking whether to display the dialog, compare the time now with the time that the dialog was last shown. If more than 2 minutes have elapsed, or if it never has been shown before, display the dialog and update the timestamp. Otherwise simply do nothing.

```
if( distance[0] > mCircle.getRadius() )
{
    long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;  //Timestamp in seconds
    if ( (timeNow - timeDialogShown) > 120 || timeDialogShown == 0)  //Show if 2 minutes have passed
    {
        timeDialogShown = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000; //Timestamp in seconds
        showAlert();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, sir.

```
final AlertDialog dialog = ....
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
  public void run() 
  {
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
}, 1000 * 60 * 2);
```

It will dismiss the dialog after 2 mins (1000 ms * 60 sec * 2 mins)

Comment: Thank you, please see my comments, I am not looking to dismiss the dialog I am looking to set a delay between showing it.

Answer (score 0):

See this -https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203816/881771
You need to setup a dismiss listener on your dialog, which blocks your showDialog() method for 2 mins.

1. Maintain a boolean value that suggest if two mins have passed since last alert was shown/dismissed.

   boolean twoMinsElapsed=true;
2. Inside your code where you are display alertDialog check this boolean value as well

   ```
   if (distance[0] > mCircle.getRadius() && twoMinsElapsed) {
              //block the showDialog() method until this value is set to true again
               twoMinsElapsed=false;
               showDialog();
           }
   ```
3. Setup a dismisslistener for your alertdialog

   alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {
                  //Set this boolean value back to true. will be called after two mins
                   twoMinsElapsed= true;
               }

           }, 120000);

       }
   });
   ```

**Consider this as a pseudo code :)**